# wkhtmltopdf Generate PDF From File Random Empty Box

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

I'm using wkhtmltopdf to create a pdf from a file (using PHP if that's important) and it's working great except for a random empty box. Here is what I've tried to get the box to go away:

1. Changed encoding for wkhtmltopdf to be UTF-8
2. Made sure the file was encoded using UTF-8
3. Checked the MySql database that it's pulling from to make sure that the encoding was UTF-8
4. Doubled/Tripled checked to make sure there is no extra character at the end of the line.
5. Deleted and re-inserted the database row
6. Rendered everything except that database row and the box wasn't there, so I know it's that entry.

Here is a copy and paste of the box from Adobe Reader in case it helps: .

I've read it could be a null object generated by wkhtmltopdf, but if it is, how can I get rid of it?

[image: The random box]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out. It appears that the issue wasn't with the text or database row at all. It was trying to use Helvetica. I'm not sure why this caused an issue on just that one row, but it did. I switched to Arial and it works perfectly.